# What exactly is Gemfire?

Tags: gemfire

I have been studying 'in-memory data grids' and saw the term 'gemfire'. I'm confused. It seems that gemfire is a term to refer to technologies that store and manipulate data like a database but in the computer memory, isn't it? What exactly is gemfire?

Which technologies can I use to work with 'in-memory data grids' in Node.js?

I saw some applications, like 'Apache Geode' and 'Pivotal gemfire'. How do I work with them? Is it like work with some cache technologies (like Redis or Memcached)? In geode's case, are the data only accessed through an API or are there other ways to access this one?

Answer (score 30):

There are many products that qualify as a "in-memory data grid", GemFire is one of the leading ones. From [this article](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/12/21/in-memory-data-grid-technologies.html) the main ones are:

> VMware Gemfire                                    (Java)
>   Oracle Coherence                                  (Java)
>   Alachisoft NCache                                 (.Net)
>   Gigaspaces XAP Elastic Caching Edition            (Java)
>   Hazelcast                                         (Java)
>   Scaleout StateServer                              (.Net)

Most of these products have drivers in many languages. You can access data in [GemFire over REST](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/rest_apps/book_intro.html), or over the native node.js client.

[Apache Geode](http://geode.incubator.apache.org/) is the open source version of GemFire. It is much more powerful than memcached and Redis; You can use Geode not only as a cache, but as a store of record (it has native persistence). It has an Object Query Language (OQL) engine built in, which allows you to query nested objects, has powerful features like [Continuous Queries](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/developing/continuous_querying/chapter_overview.html) and [replication over WAN](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/topologies_and_comm/multi_site_configuration/chapter_overview.html), among others. Geode also has protocol adapters for [memcached](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/Moving+from+memcached+to+gemcached) and [Redis](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/Geode+Redis+Adapter), allowing your memcached and Redis clients to connect to Geode.

Comment: I saw the article and Geode documentation too, they are very good, thank you. Well, now things are clearer and my researchs will be more easy and objective. Thanks for help

Comment: What more do we get in GemFire which we do not get in Geode?

Comment: WAN replication is one of the three things that Pivotal kept out of the OSS core

Comment: Since the initial release, Pivotal has donated WAN and CQ to the open source. The only additional thing in GemFire as of now is the GemFire to Green Plum connector (which enables closed loop analytics).

Comment: @Swapnil How to create entity class with join entity using Gemfire ?

Comment: Just as a side note, Redis has native persistence as well.

Answer (score 4):

I would add to the list of "In memory data grid" solutions:

- Apache Ignite
- Infinispan

They also provide powerful features.

For feature comparison you can use this website: https://db-engines.com/en/system/Hazelcast%3BIgnite .

Last note: GemFire is now a Pivotal solution.

Answer (score 0):

GemFire is a high performance distributed data management infrastructure that sits between application cluster and back-end data sources.

With GemFire, data can be managed in-memory, which makes the access faster.

Kindly check the Link below for further details

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-gemfire